# array sorting using loop and statements

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, loops, sorting

Hello friends can you fix my code like when like now the enterend input is 12 divide2 ,divide3 and divide4 to get increased from 0 to 1. or when the the input is 3,2,9 divide3 to get to value of 2 and divide2 to get 1...

Here is my code

```js
function Divider(args) {

    let n = Number(args[0]);

    let divide2 = 0.0;
    let divide3 = 0.0;
    let divide4 = 0.0;

    for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        let currentNum = Number(args[i])

        if (currentNum % 2 == 0) {
            divide2++;

        }
        if (currentNum % 3 == 0) {
            divide3++;
        }
        if (currentNum % 4 == 0) {
            divide4++;
        }


    }

    console.log(divide2);
    console.log(divide3);
    console.log(divide4);


}

Divider(['1', '12']);
```

The idea is how many numbers are divided to 2 ,3,4 without reminder to be recorded in the variables.I need it done this way.

Comment: What is the point of `let n = Number(args[0]);`? Your loop never runs because of it.

Comment: `for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {` should be `for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things,

1. Javascript provides `arguments` as a way to use the parameters passed into a function to be used as within it's scope as an array
2. While passing the arguments while calling the function, you don't need to wrap the arguments in an array. Javascript will automatically do that for you and make it available as `arguments`.
3. In the for loop, you need to iterate till i <= n and not for i < n. If there is only one number passed it at index 1, the loop won't execute.
4. You can use integers for divide2, divide3 and divide4 instead of floating point numbers.

Here is the solution after fixing your code.

```
 function Divider(args) {

    let n = Number(arguments[0]);

    let divide2 = 0.0;
    let divide3 = 0.0;
    let divide4 = 0.0;

    for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        let currentNum = Number(arguments[i])

        if (currentNum % 2 == 0) {
            divide2++;
        }
        if (currentNum % 3 == 0) {
            divide3++;
        }
        if (currentNum % 4 == 0) {
            divide4++;
        }
    }

    console.log(divide2);
    console.log(divide3);
    console.log(divide4);
}

Divider('3','3','2','9') // divide2 = 1.0, divide3 = 2.0, divide4 = 0.0 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you want, but this is what I came up with,

```js
let divide2 = 0.0;
let divide3 = 0.0;
let divide4 = 0.0;

function Divider(args) {

     for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        let currentNum = Number(args[i])
        

        if (currentNum % 2 === 0) {
            divide2++;
        }
        
        if (currentNum % 3 === 0) {
            divide3++;
            
        }
        
        if (currentNum % 4 === 0) {
            divide4++;        
       }
    }

}

 Divider(['1', '6', '9', '12', '24']);

 console.log('by2', divide2);
 console.log('by3', divide3);
 console.log('by4', divide4);
```

Comment: Thanks so much sir, i read that array.lenght is not recommended because of bad input and wanted to try by getting the first index args[0] but like this it works too.Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:

```js
function divider(n) {
    let divide2 = 0;
    let divide3 = 0;
    let divide4 = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
        let currentNum = +n[i];
        if (currentNum % 2 == 0) {
            divide2++;
        }
        if (currentNum % 3 == 0) {
            divide3++;
        }
        if (currentNum % 4 == 0) {
            divide4++;
        }
    }
    return {
        divide2,
        divide3,
        divide4
    };
}

console.log(divider(['3', '2', '9']));
```